# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Persistence

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, java-ee, wildfly

Hola buen día con todos estoy haciendo un pequeño proyectito para ir practicando jpa pero estoy presentando el sgte. error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Persistence` . Estoy usando como servidor de aplicaciones Wildfly25 y jakartaee9.

Este es mi archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.omv</groupId>
<artifactId>PruebaJPA</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

el sgte es mi archivo persistence.xml revise la documentación de wildfly junto con otros ejemplos en internet y ví que tenía que agregar un datasource por medio de la consola de wildfly asi lo hice y la conexión salió exitosa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence
      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
<!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
  <persistence-unit name="PersonaPersiste" transaction-type="JTA">
    <class>com.omv.entity.Persona</class>
    <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Y este es el código en mi clase main:

```
package com.omv.test;

 import com.omv.entity.Persona;
 import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
 import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
 import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
 import java.util.List;

 public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonaPersiste");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Persona> listaPersona = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Persona p", Persona.class).getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Registros: " + listaPersona.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
  }
  }
```

El error en consola es la sgte e indica un error en la línea 12 busque por google el problema pero no encontré solución:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Persistence
at com.omv.test.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Persistence
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Tienes que usar WildFly 25 preview porque WildFly 25 'standard' no es JakartaEE 9.

Comment: Uso la última versión la 25.0.1 final la preview para ee 9.1

Comment: Es possible listar los jars que son en el war ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día ya he solucionado el problema, como el proyecto que cree es uno de escritorio no es necesario de wildfly ya que no estoy haciendo uso de ejb y porque no es un proyecto web, así que modifiqué el archivo persistence.xml y agregué algunas dependencias al pom de la sgte manera:

Archivo persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence
      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
<!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
<persistence-unit name="PersonaPersiste" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.omv.entity.Persona</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombredetubd"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="tupassword"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Como no uso wildfly quité la etiqueta `jta-data-source` y agregué las propiedades ya mostradas para que la aplicación se conecte a la bd.

Archivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.omv</groupId>
<artifactId>PruebaJPA</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

En el archivo pom.xml era necesario agregar una implementación de jpa así que agregué eclipseLink, también lo he probado con hibernate, también agregué la dependencia de mysql y ahora me funciona todo bien. Por último un clean and build y listo, en el archivo main no toqué nada todo normal.